# will redis list of large size store data in multiple redis nodes in a cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have started reading Redis and have a query of how it internally works in multi-node distributed environment ?

1.) I created Redis list and adding 1M elements which is of size 20GB .
2.) Lets say my node capacity is 12 GB .
3.) Will redis internally split list into multiple nodes ? If so , how does it take care of insertion order while retrieving elements ?

Answer (score 0):

I think one node of Redis cluster will crash.

Because redis cluster distribute key by hash-slot, which means keys with the same hash will be distributed to the same node, and one key will only be holded on one node.So 20GB data will go to one node by key's (type is list) hash, and this node(only with 12 GB memory) will crash.

Comment: It should not crash, but refuse to insert so many items to the list.